# How can I convert String to Int?

Tags: c#, .net, string, int, type-conversion

I have a `TextBoxD1.Text` and I want to convert it to an `int` to store it in a database.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any specific drawback in using Convert.ToInt32()

Answer (score 1295, accepted):

Try this:

```
int x = Int32.Parse(TextBoxD1.Text);
```

or better yet:

```
int x = 0;

Int32.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out x);
```

Also, since [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) returns a `bool` you can use its return value to make decisions about the results of the parsing attempt:

```
int x = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out x))
{
    // you know that the parsing attempt
    // was successful
}
```

If you are curious, the difference between `Parse` and `TryParse` is best summed up like this:

> The TryParse method is like the Parse
>   method, except the TryParse method
>   does not throw an exception if the
>   conversion fails. It eliminates the
>   need to use exception handling to test
>   for a FormatException in the event
>   that s is invalid and cannot be
>   successfully parsed. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: What if the integer is 64 bit, or looks like "aslkdlksadjsd"? Is this still safe?

Comment: @Jonny `Int64.Parse()`. If the input is non-int, then you will get an execption and a stack trace with `Int64.Parse`, or the boolean `False` with `Int64.TryParse()`, so you'd need an if statement, like `if (Int32.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out x)) {}`.

Comment: You could also try to initialize the variable in the TryParse if its going to be used only inside the success condition. eg: Int32.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out int x))

Comment: Maybe this is incredibly obvious to everyone else, but for noobish people what 'out x' does is set the value of x to the string-cast-as-integer, if the casting is successful. I.e. in this case, x = 0 if the string has any non-integer characters, or x = value of string-as-integer otherwise. So the neat thing is this is one short expression which tells you if casting is successful or not, AND stores the cast integer in a variable at same time. Obviously you would often want to continue above line with 'else { // string parsed is not an integer, therefore some code to handle this situation }'

Comment: @Roberto ok, but it is possible that user (either by mistake or intentionally) type such "aslkdlksadjsd" value inside a textbox! so should our program crash?

Comment: I meant that "aslkdlksadjsd" is not an integer, so you should say "what if the string is aslkdlksadjsd"

Comment: NOTE: Re. the result, x: "This parameter is passed uninitialized; any value originally supplied in result will be overwritten."  [Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Int32.TryParse);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8 ]

Comment: `using System;`

Comment: C# 7+ : out var x. 
Starting with C# 7.0, you can declare the out variable in the argument list of the method call, rather than in a separate variable declaration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

Comment: `if ( int.TryParse(stringValue, out int intValue) )`

Comment: you could also use `int.Parse(TextBoxD1.Text)`

Answer (score 90):

```
Convert.ToInt32( TextBoxD1.Text );
```

Use this if you feel confident that the contents of the text box is a valid `int`. A safer option is

```
int val = 0;
Int32.TryParse( TextBoxD1.Text, out val );
```

This will provide you with some default value you can use. `Int32.TryParse` also returns a Boolean value indicating whether it was able to parse or not, so you can even use it as the condition of an `if` statement.

```
if( Int32.TryParse( TextBoxD1.Text, out val ){
  DoSomething(..);
} else {
  HandleBadInput(..);
}
```

Comment: -1 RE. "This will provide you with some default value you can use." If you mean val, expect trouble:  "This parameter is passed uninitialized; any value originally supplied in result will be overwritten."  [Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Int32.TryParse);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8 ]

Comment: 10 years ago me apologizes.

Comment: **@BabakNaffas & @PeterMortensen -** I tried ``Convert.ToInt32(text)`` and I'm confident that there's a number in there, but **Visual Studio** is yelling at me that it **Cannot implicitly convert the string to int**. Please help.

Comment: @jewishspiderweb, what is the full value of `text`? Are there white spaces? Do you need to trim? Is the value out of range for an int?

Comment: **No**. I've figured it out by using ``TryParse``. Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

```
int.TryParse()
```

It won't throw if the text is not numeric.

Comment: This is better than the other two. User input is likely to be the wrong format. This one is more efficient than using exception handling like the others require.

Comment: Exactly. It returns false if the conversion failed.

Answer (score 27):

```
int myInt = int.Parse(TextBoxD1.Text)
```

Another way would be:

```
bool isConvertible = false;
int myInt = 0;

isConvertible = int.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out myInt);
```

The difference between the two is that the first one would throw an exception if the value in your textbox can't be converted, whereas the second one would just return false.

Comment: The above boolean variable is very useful we are using the converted value for comaprison, let say in an if clause.  `code`  int NumericJL;
                bool isNum = int.TryParse(nomeeJobBand, out NumericJL);
                if (isNum)//The the retured JL is able to pasred to int then go ahead for comparison
                {
                    if (!(NumericJL >= 6))
                    {
                      //Nominate
                    }
                    //else {}}

Answer (score 17):

Be careful when using `Convert.ToInt32()` on a char!
It will return the [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) code of the character!

If you access the string only in a certain position using the `[i]` indexing operator, it will return a `char` and not a `string`!

```
String input = "123678";
                    ^
                    |
int indexOfSeven =  4;

int x = Convert.ToInt32(input[indexOfSeven]);             // Returns 55

int x = Convert.ToInt32(input[indexOfSeven].toString());  // Returns 7
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to parse the string, and you also need to ensure that it is truly in the format of an integer.

The easiest way is this:

```
int parsedInt = 0;
if (int.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out parsedInt))
{
   // Code for if the string was valid
}
else
{
   // Code for if the string was invalid
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Enjoy it...

```
int i = 0;
string s = "123";
i = int.Parse(s);
i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
int x = Int32.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out x) ? x : 0;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
int x = 0;
int.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out x);
```

The TryParse statement returns a boolean representing whether the parse has succeeded or not. If it succeeded, the parsed value is stored into the second parameter.

See *[Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)* for more detailed information.

Answer (score 11):

While there are already many solutions here that describe `int.Parse`, there's something important missing in all the answers. Typically, the string representations of numeric values differ by culture. Elements of numeric strings such as currency symbols, group (or thousands) separators, and decimal separators all vary by culture.

If you want to create a robust way to parse a string to an integer, it's therefore important to take the culture information into account. If you don't, the [current culture settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) will be used. That might give a user a pretty nasty surprise -- or even worse, if you're parsing file formats. If you just want English parsing, it's best to simply make it explicit, by specifying the culture settings to use:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US");
int result = 0;
if (int.TryParse(myString, NumberStyles.Integer, culture, out result))
{
    // use result...
}
```

For more information, read up on CultureInfo, specifically [NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 9):

**You can write your own extension method**

```
public static class IntegerExtensions
{
    public static int ParseInt(this string value, int defaultValue = 0)
    {
        int parsedValue;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out parsedValue))
        {
            return parsedValue;
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }

    public static int? ParseNullableInt(this string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value.ParseInt();
    }
}
```

**And wherever in code just call**

```
int myNumber = someString.ParseInt(); // Returns value or 0
int age = someString.ParseInt(18); // With default value 18
int? userId = someString.ParseNullableInt(); // Returns value or null
```

**In this concrete case**

```
int yourValue = TextBoxD1.Text.ParseInt();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the class be called `StringExtensions` instead of `IntegerExtensions`, since these extension methods act on a `string` and not on an `int`?

Answer (score 9):

Conversion of `string` to `int` can be done for: `int`, `Int32`, `Int64` and other data types reflecting integer data types in .NET

Below example shows this conversion:

This shows (for info) data adapter element initialized to int value. The same can be done directly like,

```
int xxiiqVal = Int32.Parse(strNabcd);
```

Ex.

```
string strNii = "";
UsrDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Nii"].Value = Int32.Parse(strNii );
```

[Link to see this demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcdKTbHT_mY).

Answer (score 8):

As explained in the [TryParse documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx), TryParse() returns a Boolean which indicates that a valid number was found:

```
bool success = Int32.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out val);

if (success)
{
    // Put val in database
}
else
{
    // Handle the case that the string doesn't contain a valid number
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can convert string to int many different type methods in C#

First one is mostly use :

```
string test = "123";
int x = Convert.ToInt16(test);
```

if int value is higher you should use int32 type.

Second one:

```
int x = int.Parse(text);
```

if you want to error check, you can use TryParse method. In below I add nullable type;

```
int i=0;
Int32.TryParse(text, out i) ? i : (int?)null);
```

Enjoy your codes....

Answer (score 5):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxD1.Text);
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., how is it different from [Babak Naffas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int/1019803#1019803)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use either,

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxD1.Text);
```

or

```
int i = int.Parse(TextBoxD1.Text);
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 5):

```
//May be quite some time ago but I just want throw in some line for any one who may still need it

int intValue;
string strValue = "2021";

try
{
    intValue = Convert.ToInt32(strValue);
}
catch
{
    //Default Value if conversion fails OR return specified error
    // Example 
    intValue = 2000;
}
```

Comment: Defaulting in this case would not be a good idea. If at all defaulting is required crucially, I recommend returning 0.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like below without TryParse or inbuilt functions:

```
static int convertToInt(string a)
{
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        int temp = a[i] - '0';
        if (temp != 0)
        {
            x += temp * (int)Math.Pow(10, (a.Length - (i+1)));
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: convertToInt("1234") gives 10000......if you are going to copy the answer of someone else, at least copy the whole thing

Comment: don't compare me with yourself.. add updated solution instead .. lol

Comment: @SerenityNow you can check now.It was typo mistake.

Comment: referring to your id, a _lazy_-developer will not create such method! ;D good

Answer (score 4):

You also may use an [extension method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method), so it will be more readable (although everybody is already used to the regular Parse functions).

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a string to int.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The string to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>The converted integer.</returns>
    public static int ParseToInt32(this string value)
    {
        return int.Parse(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks whether the value is integer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The string to check.</param>
    /// <param name="result">The out int parameter.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the value is an integer; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public static bool TryParseToInt32(this string value, out int result)
    {
        return int.TryParse(value, out result);
    }
}
```

And then you can call it that way:

1. If you are sure that your string is an integer, like "50".

   ```
   int num = TextBoxD1.Text.ParseToInt32();
   ```
2. If you are not sure and want to prevent crashes.

   ```
   int num;
   if (TextBoxD1.Text.TryParseToInt32(out num))
   {
       //The parse was successful, the num has the parsed value.
   }
   ```

To make it more dynamic, so you can parse it also to double, float, etc., you can make a generic extension.

Answer (score 4):

This would do

```
string x = TextBoxD1.Text;
int xi = Convert.ToInt32(x);
```

Or you can use

```
int xi = Int32.Parse(x);
```

Refer [Microsoft Developer Network for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number)

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a string to int in C# using:

Functions of convert class i.e. `Convert.ToInt16()`, `Convert.ToInt32()`, `Convert.ToInt64()` or by using `Parse` and `TryParse` Functions. Examples are given [here](https://www.codeslehrer.com/c-string-to-int/).

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 4):

In case you know the string is an integer do:

```
int value = int.Parse(TextBoxD1.Text);
```

In case you don't know the string is an integer do it safely with `TryParse`.

In `C# 7.0` you can use [inline variable declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0018).

- If parse successes - value = its parsed value.
- If parse fails - value = 0.

Code:

```
if (int.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out int value))
{
    // Parse succeed
}
```

Drawback:

You cannot differentiate between a 0 value and a non parsed value.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert string to an integer value with the help of parse method.

Eg:

```
int val = Int32.parse(stringToBeParsed);
int x = Int32.parse(1234);
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 3):

In C# v.7 you could use an inline out parameter, without an additional variable declaration:

```
int.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out int x);
```

Comment: Aren't `out` parameters discouraged in C# now?

Answer (score 2):

The way I always do this is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace example_string_to_int
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a = textBox1.Text;
            // This turns the text in text box 1 into a string
            int b;
            if (!int.TryParse(a, out b))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This is not a number");
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.Text = a+" is a number" ;
            }
            // Then this 'if' statement says if the string is not a number, display an error, else now you will have an integer.
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers are good but for information, we can use `int.TryParse` which is safe to convert string to int, for example

```
// TryParse returns true if the conversion succeeded
// and stores the result in j.
int j;
if (Int32.TryParse("-105", out j))
   Console.WriteLine(j);
else
   Console.WriteLine("String could not be parsed.");
// Output: -105
```

TryParse never throws an exception—even on invalid input and null. It is overall preferable to `int.Parse` in most program contexts.

Source: [How to convert string to int in C#? (With Difference between Int.Parse and Int.TryParse)](https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-c/159)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. It will work:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxD1.Text);
```

The string value in the variable TextBoxD1.Text will be converted into Int32 and will be stored in x.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the long way, just create your one method:

```
static int convertToInt(string a)
{
    int x = 0;
        
    Char[] charArray = a.ToCharArray();
    int j = charArray.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
    {
        j--;
        int s = (int)Math.Pow(10, j);

        x += ((int)Char.GetNumericValue(charArray[i]) * s);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

METHOD 1

```
int  TheAnswer1 = 0;
bool Success = Int32.TryParse("42", out TheAnswer1);
if (!Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("String not Convertable to an Integer");
}
```

METHOD 2

```
int TheAnswer2 = 0;
try {
    TheAnswer2 = Int32.Parse("42");
}
catch {
    Console.WriteLine("String not Convertable to an Integer");
}
```

METHOD 3

```
int TheAnswer3 = 0;
try {
    TheAnswer3 = Int32.Parse("42");
}
catch (FormatException) {
    Console.WriteLine("String not in the correct format for an Integer");
}
catch (ArgumentNullException) {
    Console.WriteLine("String is null");
}
catch (OverflowException) {
    Console.WriteLine("String represents a number less than"
                      + "MinValue or greater than MaxValue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree on using the `TryParse` method, a lot of people dislike the use of `out` parameter (myself included). With tuple support having been added to C#, an alternative is to create an extension method that will limit the number of times you use `out` to a single instance:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static (int result, bool canParse) TryParse(this string s)
    {
        int res;
        var valid = int.TryParse(s, out res);
        return (result: res, canParse: valid);
    }
}
```

(Source: [C# how to convert a string to int](https://blog.elmah.io/csharp-how-to-convert-a-string-to-int/))

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version of doing it via an Extension Method that has an option to set the default value as well, if the converting fails. In fact, this is what I used to convert a string input to any convertible type:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static TOutput AsOrDefault<TOutput>(this string input, TOutput defaultValue = default)
        where TOutput : IConvertible
    {
        TOutput output = defaultValue;

        try
        {
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TOutput));
            if (converter != null)
            {
                output = (TOutput)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return output;
    }
}
```

For my usage, I limited the output to be one of the convertible types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=net-5.0. I don't need crazy logics to convert a string to a class, for example.

To use it to convert a string to int:

```cs
using FluentAssertions;
using Xunit;

[Theory]
[InlineData("0", 0)]
[InlineData("1", 1)]
[InlineData("123", 123)]
[InlineData("-123", -123)]
public void ValidStringWithNoDefaultValue_ReturnsExpectedResult(string input, int expectedResult)
{
    var result = input.AsOrDefault<int>();

    result.Should().Be(expectedResult);
}

[Theory]
[InlineData("0", 999, 0)]
[InlineData("1", 999, 1)]
[InlineData("123", 999, 123)]
[InlineData("-123", -999, -123)]
public void ValidStringWithDefaultValue_ReturnsExpectedResult(string input, int defaultValue, int expectedResult)
{
    var result = input.AsOrDefault(defaultValue);

    result.Should().Be(expectedResult);
}

[Theory]
[InlineData("")]
[InlineData(" ")]
[InlineData("abc")]
public void InvalidStringWithNoDefaultValue_ReturnsIntegerDefault(string input)
{
    var result = input.AsOrDefault<int>();

    result.Should().Be(default(int));
}

[Theory]
[InlineData("", 0)]
[InlineData(" ", 1)]
[InlineData("abc", 234)]
public void InvalidStringWithDefaultValue_ReturnsDefaultValue(string input, int defaultValue)
{
    var result = input.AsOrDefault(defaultValue);

    result.Should().Be(defaultValue);
}
```