# How to convert string to integer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, int, type-conversion

How do I convert a string to an integer in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int

Answer (score 151):

If you're sure it'll parse correctly, use

```
int.Parse(string)
```

If you're not, use

```
int i;
bool success = int.TryParse(string, out i);
```

**Caution!** In the case below, `i` will equal 0, not 10 after the `TryParse`.

```
int i = 10;
bool failure = int.TryParse("asdf", out i);
```

This is because `TryParse` uses an *out* parameter, not a *ref* parameter.

Comment: @sslaitha, thanks. If it answered your question sufficiently, please remember to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Just note that if you have int i = 10;  and use int.TryParse("asdf", out i); that i will contain 0 not 10!!!  This is because TryParse uses an out variable, not a ref.

Comment: The "caution" applies to the third example - not the second one. Had me puzzled for a bit since I expected the "this" to refer to the example above, not below.

Answer (score 27):

```
int myInt = System.Convert.ToInt32(myString);
```

As several others have mentioned, you can also use `int.Parse()` and `int.TryParse()`.

If you're certain that the `string` will always be an `int`:

```
int myInt = int.Parse(myString);
```

If you'd like to check whether `string` is really an `int` first:

```
int myInt;
bool isValid = int.TryParse(myString, out myInt); // the out keyword allows the method to essentially "return" a second value
if (isValid)
{
    int plusOne = myInt + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
int a = int.Parse(myString);
```

or better yet, look into `int.TryParse(string)`

Answer (score 6):

Do something like:

```
var result = Int32.Parse(str);
```

Comment: i meet error Value was either too large or too small for an Int32

Answer (score 6):

```
string varString = "15";
int i = int.Parse(varString);
```

or

```
int varI;
string varString = "15";
int.TryParse(varString, out varI);
```

`int.TryParse` is safer since if you put something else in `varString` (for example "fsfdsfs") you would get an exception. By using `int.TryParse` when string can't be converted into int it will return `0`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure that you have "real" number in your string, or you are comfortable of any exception that might arise, use this.

```
string s="4";
int a=int.Parse(s);
```

For some more control over the process, use

```
string s="maybe 4";
int a;
if (int.TryParse(s, out a)) {
    // it's int;
}
else {
    // it's no int, and there's no exception;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[4 techniques are benchmarked here.](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int)

The fastest way turned out to be the following:

```
y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
       y = y * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
```

"s" is your string that you want converted to an int. This code assumes you won't have any exceptions during the conversion. So if you know your string data will always be some sort of int value, the above code is the best way to go for pure speed.

At the end, "y" will have your int value.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i;
string whatever;

//Best since no exception raised
int.TryParse(whatever, out i);

//Better use try catch on this one
i = Convert.ToInt32(whatever);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool result = Int32.TryParse(someString, out someNumeric)
```

This method will try to convert `someString` into `someNumeric`, and return a `result` depending on whether or not the conversion is successful: `true` if conversion is successful and `false` if conversion failed. Take note that this method will not throw an exception if the conversion failed like how `Int32.Parse` method did and instead returns zero for `someNumeric`.

For more information, you can read here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

& 
[How to convert string to integer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344411/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;

string result = Something;

i = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyMath
{
    public dynamic Sum(dynamic x, dynamic y)
    {
        return (x+y);
    }
}

class Demo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyMath d = new MyMath();
        Console.WriteLine(d.Sum(23.2, 32.2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either,

```
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(myString);
```

or

```
    int i =int.Parse(myString);
```