# Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#

I need convert **String** of input of table database to **Integer value** in C# .NET 4 and tried this code inspired from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344411/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-c-sharp):

```
    int i;
    string Entry_Level = Convert.ToInt32("2,45");
    i = Convert.ToInt32(Entry_Level);
```

But I've this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

**EDIT**

Solved with:

```
    decimal i;
    string Entry_Level = "2,45";
    i = Convert.ToDecimal(Entry_Level);

    Response.Write(i.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

In output I've 2,45, many thanks!

Comment: What `int` value are you expecting?

Comment: thank you, I expect 2.45

Comment: @user3436943 2.45 is not an `int`...

Comment: That is not an `int`.

Comment: Could be `double` or `decimal` depending on what the value represents.

Comment: This may be of more use to you then: [Parse String to Double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double)

Comment: @user3436943 I don't really understand the update to your question. And I don't understand why you accepted an answer that doesn't cover conversion from string to decimal/double.

Comment: This is the weirdest question I've ever seen here. The accepted answer doesn't reflect the problem, the used code doesn't reflect the answer, and all in all, it's like going from Berlin to Paris through Moscow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string Entry_Level = Convert.ToInt32("2,45");
```

should be

```
string Entry_Level = "2,45";
```

Why not go for this though:

```
int i = 2,45;
```

But since this is not an integer, you'll need one of the built-in decimal types:

```
/* use this when precision matters a lot, for example when this is a unit price or a percentage value that will be multiplied with big numbers */
decimal i = 2.45 


/*  use this when precision isn't the most important part. 
It's still really precise, but you can get in trouble when dealing with really small or really big numbers. 
Doubles are fine in most cases.*/
double i = 2.45
```

See [this thread for more information about decimal vs double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when).

Comment: This is fine, but neglects any consideration of what happens when you pass `"2,45"` to `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: The double vs decimal issue is not one of precision. It's about binary or decimal representation.

Comment: It's not exactly about precision, but precision does come into play when comparing the two. I've added a link with a full explanation of decimal vs double

Comment: I have a solid understanding of the difference between decimal and double, and I am here to tell you that the key issue is decimal vs binary rather than precision.

Answer (score 2):

The value `2,45` does not represent an integer. It is a real value. So I believe that you are actually looking for `Convert.ToDouble` or `Convert.ToDecimal`. Or perhaps `double.Parse` or `decimal.Parse`.

You may also need to consider what happens when you run your code on a machine that does not use `,` as the decimal separator. Consider using the overloads that accept `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
string Entry_Level = Convert.ToInt32("2,45").toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the line of code below which will remove your compile error but it will through and Runtime Exception cause 2,45 is not  a valid integer.

```
string Entry_Level = Convert.ToInt32("2,45").ToString();
```

I will suggest you to write the below line of codes which will help you to get the value 2.45 on your variable named i

```
decimal i;
string Entry_Level = "2,45";
Entry_Level = Entry_Level.Replace(',', '.');
i = Convert.ToDecimal(Entry_Level);
```