# How to fix a "cs0029" error in a C# program?

Tags: c#

This is my code, and I can't find the problem. I don't understand the error it's putting out.

using System;

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var Number = 0;
while ((Number < 1) | (Number > 10))  {
  Console.WriteLine("Enter a positive whole number: ");
  Number = Console.ReadLine();
  if (Number > 10) {
    Console.WriteLine("Number too large.");
  } else {
    if (Number < 1) {
      Console.WriteLine("Not a positive number.");
    }
  }
}
var c = 1;
for (int k = 0; k < Number - 1; k++) {
  Console.WriteLine(c);
  c = (c * (Number - 1 - k)) % (k + 1);
}
;
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: Line numbers/stacktrace ect would be helpful here. At a glance I doubt `(Number < 1) | (Number > 10)` is intended - should be `(Number < 1) || (Number > 10)` ?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055775/compiler-error-message-cs0029-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-string. Console.ReadLine() returns a string and you cannot compare a string to an int (in your if). You have to transform the Console.ReadLine return to an int with int.Parse().

Answer (score 0):

I might say that you are having a type error, look when you put an input you receive an "string" then you are trying to compare it against a "int" type which in C# are not equivalents, so you have to cast your input to "int"

```
int Number = 0;
Number = (int)Console.ReadLine();
```

By doing so, btw, you might have another error there, if you try to write a "string" into that input. So keep it to numbers :) gl

Answer (score 0):

[Compiler Error CS0029](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029)

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type'

You are trying to convert a `string` into an `int`. They are completely different types. however, there are methods to *parse* `strings` to `int`, since this is user input the best such method would be the [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) method

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
> integer equivalent. **A return value indicates whether the operation
> succeeded**.

```
var number = 0;
while ((number < 1) | (number > 10))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter a positive whole number: ");
   if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
      Console.WriteLine("You didn't even enter a number");
   else if (number > 10)
      Console.WriteLine("Number too large.");
   else if (number < 1)
      Console.WriteLine("Not a positive number.");
}
```

Another approach would be to combine the checks

```
var number = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter a positive whole number between 1 and 10 : ");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) || number > 10 || number <= 0)
   Console.WriteLine("You failed, try again");

Console.WriteLine(number);
```