# Setting an ID as an Integer with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, integer

I am currently using the following script to set this value as a String:

`string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();`

However, I'd now like to store it as an Integer.

How do I do this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to throw a server error on a bad string

```
int id=0;
if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"],out id)) {
  .. logic for valid id
} else {
  .. logic for invalid id
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `ToString()`, the `QueryString` property already returns indexed values as strings.

Comment: @QuickJoeSmith Doh, was on automatic I meant to remove that.  Now updated

Comment: For all I know, redundant call is probably optimised away anyway.

Comment: You don't really need the .QueryString part either, you can just do Request["ID"], although using the Request.QueryString is a bit more readable

Comment: Bear in mind that `Request[key]` will search server variables, cookies and form fields as well as the query string. There are plenty of situations in which where a value comes from is just as important as what its value is.

Answer (score 3):

```
int ID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use either of these:

If you *know* that you have an ID:

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
int integerId = int.Parse(ID);
```

or, if the query string may be missing or invalid (never trust query strings....)

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
int integerId;
if (int.TryParse(ID, out integerId))
{
   // you have a valid integer ID here.
   // process it
}
else
{
    // handle missing or invalid ID
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
```

or

```
int i;
Int32.TryParse(ID, out i);
```

BTW `Request.QueryString["ID"]` is already a string so the following is fine:

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int ID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
```

See [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();

int id=int.Parse(ID);
```

or

```
int id=Convert.ToInt16(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use tryparse for querystring values if you want to convert it to integer even if you never set it to string , because user can change that anytime before sending request (visible in URL).

int id = 0 ;//default value

bool success = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"],out id))

if (success) {
//write code for default value action
return;
}

//write code for other values.