# How can I convert a string to int?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

```
public List<int> GetListIntKey(int keys)
{
        int j;
        List<int> t;
        t = new List<int>();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            j = GetKey((keys + i).ToString());
            if (j == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                t.Add(j);
            }
        }
        if (t.Count == 0)
            return null;
        else
            return t;
}
```

The problem is on the line:

```
j = GetKey((keys + i).ToString());
```

I'm getting error say:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Now the `GetKey` function is type of string:

```
public string GetKey(string key)
{
}
```

What should I do ?

Comment: This question asks about converting an int to a string, but you already figured that out, and the error message is about converting a string to an int.

Comment: Please edit your question and correct its title. The problem is about string to int conversion, not int to string.

Comment: I like how most of the correct answers are downvoted.

Comment: This is an almost duplicate question with lots of correct answers (and lots of down votes followed by counter strike up votes). This question definitely fail on adding value to SO and should be closed as duplicate as @hvd suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the result type of your getkey is string en the j variable is declared int

the solution is:

```
j = Convert.ToInt32(GetKey((keys + i).ToString()));
```

i hope this is solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

The Problem is that "j" is an int, and you are assigning it to the return of GetKey.  Either make "j" a string, or change the return type of GetKey to int.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
j = Int32.Parse(GetKey((keys + i).ToString()));
```

It will throw an exception if the value is not a valid integer.

An alternative is the `TryParse`, which returns a boolean if the conversion was not successful:

```
j = 0;

Int32.TryParse(GetKey((keys + i).ToString()), out j);
// this returns false when the value is not a valid integer.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because GetKey returns a string and you are trying to assign the return object to j which is declared as an int.  You need to do as alfonso suggested and convert the return value to an int.  You can also use:

```
j = Convert.ToInt32(GetKey((keys+i).ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

try to improve your code, and look this:

```
public List<int> GetListIntKey(int keys)
{
    var t = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        var j = GetKey((keys + i).ToString());
        int n;
        // check if it's possible to convert a number, because j is a string.
        if (int.TryParse(j, out n))
            // if it works, add on the list
            t.Add(n);
        else //otherwise it is not a number, null, empty, etc...
            break;
    }
    return t.Count == 0 ? null : t;
}
```

I hope it help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
What should i do ?
```

You have it all wrong. Read about value types and reference types.

**Errors:**

1. Error is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'`. Meaning implicitly it is getting a string which it cannot convert to int. GetKeys is returning string which you are trying to assign to integer `j`.
2. Your j is integer. How can it be checked with null. When can a value type be null?

Use this

```
public List<int> GetListIntKey(int keys)
{
    int j = 0;
    List<int> t = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        string s = GetKey((keys + i).ToString());

        if (Int.TryParse(s, out j))
            break;
        else
            t.Add(j);
    }

    if (t.Count == 0)
        return null;
    else
        return t;
}
```

Comment: "Learn some programming" was uncalled for and rude.  We all start somewhere and the last thing we need is to have someone belittling us when we're reaching out for help.

Comment: @DarvisLombardo: Corrected. Point Taken. Reverse Downvote.

Comment: @daniloquio: I want +10. but i wont even get that. My current limit for the day (200) is reached.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use an exppicit type cast.

Use

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(aString);
```

to convert.

Comment: 1. he wants to convert int to string 2. this is a c# question.

Comment: @Femaref re. 1: no, he doesn't. The question title is wrong, the error message is about a string-to-int conversion.

Comment: I was to fast as to see what language was tagged ;) ive corrected ...