# how can i change queryString value to (int)

Tags: c#, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

how can i change queryString value to an (int)

```
string str_id;
str_id = Request.QueryString["id"];
int id = (int)str_id;
```

Comment: Dear, use google before asking any question :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Int32.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to get `int` value safely:

```
int id;
string str_id = Request.QueryString["id"];
if(int.TryParse(str_id,out id))
{
    //id now contains your int value
}
else
{
    //str_id contained something else, i.e. not int
}
```

Comment: +1 for `TryParse()`, never trust user input.

Answer (score 3):

replace with this one

```
string str_id;
str_id = Request.QueryString["id"];
int id = Convert.ToInt32(str_id);
```

or simply and more efficient one

```
string str_id;
str_id = Request.QueryString["id"];
int id = int.Parse(str_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(str_id, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do that

```
string str_id = Request.QueryString["id"];

int id = 0;

//this prevent exception being thrown in case query string value is not a valid integer
Int32.TryParse(str_id, out id); //returns true if str_id is a valid integer and set the value of id to the value. False otherwise and id remains zero
```

Others

```
int id = Int32.Parse(str_id); //will throw exception if string is not valid integer
int id = Convert.ToInt32(str_id);  //will throw exception if string is not valid integer
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `int.Parse(str_id)`

**Edit**  : don't trust user input

it's better to check if the input is a number or not before parsing , for this use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)