# How to convert document.body.innertext to integer

Tags: c#

I know that I'm able to convert things to string with `.ToString()` but I'm not sure how I would go about converting something to an integer.

```
        int version = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText;
        if (version > 0.0.1)
        {

        }
```

Thats what I have so far

I'm trying to convert innertext to an integer, not trying to convert general things to integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert String to Int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Comment: use this http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-parse

Comment: @Alex, that is not an exact duplicate.  You cannot covert a typical version string to a number with parsing it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BsIYW8x.png I still get an error

Comment: @BlackFrog you are right,

Comment: Looks to me that you are actually looking to convert to `Version` class, not to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following, based upon the format you expect, i.e. a version number consisting of integer parts separated by a dot ('.'):

```
var version = webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerText
   .Split('.') // this splits the string into number parts
   .Select(p => Int32.Parse(p)) // this converts each number part to an int
   .ToArray() // this returns them as an array of integer values.

// This prints the version components
if (version.Length == 1)
    Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", version[0]);
else if (version.Length == 2) 
    Console.WriteLine("Version: Major = {0}, Minor = {1}", version[0], version[1]);
else if (version.Length == 3)
    Console.WriteLine("Version: Major = {0}, Minor = {1}, Increment = {2}", version[0], version[1], version[2]);
else if (version.Length == 3)
    Console.WriteLine("Version: Major = {0}, Minor = {1}, Increment = {2}, BuildNumber = {3}", version[0], version[1], version[2], version[4]);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Version contains more than 4 ({0}) parts", version.Length);
```

Note, that this is not a **single** integer that you will get returned. You have to access the components individually if you want to do a comparison, I.e. compare `version[0]` with the `major` version that you are expecting, `version[1]` with the `minor` version component, etc.

A standard class that is already available specifically for version numbers formatted in this way is the [Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Version(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You can create one from your text by doing this:

```
var version = new Version(webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerText);
// or alternatively:
//var version = Version.Parse(webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerText);

Console.WriteLine(version);
```

If you want to compare this with another version (let's say "2.3.1"), you
can do that like this:

```
var otherVersion = new Version("2.3.1");
// Or alternatively:
// var otherVersion = new Version(2, 3, 1);

// this compares two versions
var compareResult = version.CompareTo(otherVersion);
if (compareResult < 0)
    Console.WriteLine("version < otherVersion");
else if (compareResult > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("version > otherVersion");
else
    Console.WriteLine("version == otherVersion");
```

When applied to the code snippet in your question, you can use it like this:

```
var currentVersion = new Version("0.0.1");
var version = Version.Parse(webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerText);
if (version.CompareTo(currentVersion) > 0)
{
     // version is newer (higher) than our current version of "0.0.1"
}
```

Comment: I was following up until the last part. I'm not sure how I would go about comparing the version number to another integer with this code?

Comment: @pshyoulost can you follow it now? It looks to me like your easiest option is to use the `Version` class. What exactly is it that you are trying to compare the version from `webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerText` with?

Comment: It makes a lot more sense now. Thanks. I'm trying to compare it to the current version number of the program

Comment: @pshyoulost ok, sample usage attached at the end of the answer

Answer (score 1):

A number with two decimal points is not a number.

Here is an example:

```
using System;

namespace so29713053
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string version = "0.0.2";

            Console.WriteLine("Checking if version match 0.0.1");
            if (version == "0.0.1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  version match");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  version doesn't match");
            }


            Console.WriteLine("\nChecking if version match 0.0.2");
            if (version == "0.0.2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  version match");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  version doesn't match");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nCheck version using string.compare...");
            switch (string.Compare(version, "0.0.1"))
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("   version match");
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("   version is newer");
                    break;

                case -1:
                    Console.WriteLine("   version is older");
                    break;
            }

            // or you can go deep - code need error checking
            string[] parts = version.Split('.');
            string major = parts[0];
            string minor = parts[1];
            string revision = parts[2];

            // compare each parts of the version number
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output from Console Code Sample above]

Comment: How does visual basic know if a string is great than another string. Does that even make sense?

Comment: string comparison is using ASCII order.  So "0.0.2" is larger then "0.0.1"

Comment: This is incorrect. As @pshyoulost mentioned, how will you compare strings?

Comment: Well when I did that I got an error saying I'm not able to use a `>` to compare strings

Comment: @BlackFrog Just say when

Comment: @BlackFrog A bit overwhelmed with what you're saying to be honest =/