# How to convert a string value into "int" in c#.net

Tags: c#, type-conversion

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string b = "hello";
    TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(b).ToString();
}
```

**Error:**

> [Input string was not in a correct format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WoNa.png) .How do I convert a
>   string to an integer in C#?

Comment: What hello supposed to be as number?

Comment: Did you read any document about `Convert` class?

Comment: Have you already seen the below post ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int

Comment: You are converting an `string` to `int` and again from `int` to `string` this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

```
 string b = "hello";
 Int32 outPut=0;
 Int32.TryParse(b,out outPut);//0
 TextBox1.Text = outPut.ToString();
```

Since b holds a string that cannot be converted to integer you will get `0` in `TextBox1`.

`Int32.Parse()` and `Convert.Int32()` are other possible methods of converting string to integer. but both these methods are not capable of handles `null` as well as they convert only if the input to the methord is convertible to integer, otherwise it throws **format exception**.

> Where as `Int32.TryParse()` will not throws any exception on wrong
>   input, it gives `0` in the case of wrong input. and return a `Boolean`
>   value that indicates whether the conversion is successful or not.