# xamarin convert entry text to numeric value

Tags: xamarin, type-conversion, gtk#

I'm new user of Xamarin studio 5.9.5 (build 9) on Windows, and I want make a form based application that involves some mathematical calculations (.Net + Gtk#).

I made a simple form containing 3 Entry widgets (2 for input values and 1 for output value) and 1 button. Here is the code for the button (simple addition Entry3 = Entry1 + Entry2)

```
using System;
using Gtk;
...    
protected void OnBtnClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            entry3.Text = entry1.Text + entry2.Text;
            //throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }
```

As you can see, this code just makes a concatenation of both text fields.

How can I convert the text fields into numeric values in order to achieve mathematical addition (and other calculations) ?

Thanks

Comment: you have to convert `string` to `int`, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk clear, precise and concise, I found that same is done for double/string conversion too using either "Convert.ToDouble",  "Double.Parse" and "Double.TryParse" methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

Comment: just give my comment "up" ;)

Comment: I don't find where I can give "up" to your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// assuming these values are ints
int val1 = int.Parse(entry1.Text);
int val2 = int.Parse(entry2.Text);
entry3.Text = val1 + val2;
```