# Why is my int value giving me a error when changing it?

Tags: c#, timer, intervals

I am new to C# and I am trying to understand the timer feature..
I made a label, a textbox and a button also added a timer ofcourse.

I have a int set to 1000 = 1 second.

I would like to be able to enter a value into the textbox i.e 5 
and then the timer uses that as its interval between every tick.

For some reason its saying "Cannot implicitly convert type "string to int"

And I have no idea on how to convert a string to an int..

Any examples? Would help me so much!

```
namespace Clicker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int count = 0;
        int interval = 1000;


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            interval = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            label1.Text = count.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert String to Int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Answer (score 5):

```
 interval = textBox1.Text;
```

interval is an integer and textBox1.Text is a string.
You have to parse the value like:

```
interval = int.Parse(textBox1.Text)
```

or better use int.TryParse!

also you can find this here:
[String to Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. You are trying to assign a `string` to an `int`. Specifically, on this line:

```
interval = textBox1.Text;
```

You need to use the [`Int32.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) method to convert the `string` data:

```
interval = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 1000;
```

That being said, you are not actually using your `interval` variable for anything. You need to assign the timer's `Interval` property before starting the timer:

```
interval = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 1000;
timer1.Interval = interval;
timer1.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

`interval` is of type `int`. The property `Text` on the `TextBox` control is a `string`.

You need to convert/parse the value to an `int` to use it e.g:

```
int userInput = 0;

if(Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out userInput))
{
    interval = userInput;
}
else
{
    // Input couldn't be converted to an int, throw an error etc...
}
```