# How to convert String taken from a TextField view to an int in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

to convert int to string in text field ( visual studio)

```
int id = int.parse(textfield1.Text).ToString();
```

it makes error please do solve this ?

Comment: Please read the error, it says what you did wrong. That's the purpose of error and it's messages.

Comment: `ToString()` converts an object type to a string type. Why would need it to map the value to an `int` type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need To.String on the end.

Just

```
int id = int.Parse(textfield1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

the first try that may come to your mind is to do:

```
var id = textfield1.Text;
Console.WriteLine(id);
```

or

```
var id = int.Parse(textfield1.Text);
```

but that is not safe at all (what if textfield1 is holding something that can not be converted into an integer?)

that is why the best way you take should be.

```
//here the result of the conversion
var output = -1;
// a variable to verify whether the result was ok or not.
var resultOk = Int32.TryParse(textfield1.Text, out output);  

Console.WriteLine(output );
```

Comment: no need to assign `output`, however. `TryParse` will do that for you (out params are guaranteed to be assigned).

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo parse should be Parse =>int.Parse and you don't need the tostring after that because you are converting it back to string

```
 int id = int.Parse(textfield1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting it back to string again when calling `.ToString()`
just use

```
int id = int.parse(textfield1.Text);
```

or this to avoid invalid values

```
int id;
if(int.TryParse(textfield1.Text,out id)){
  //Valid value
}
else
{
  //Invalid value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To convert int to string, you can use one of following methods :**

**1.**

```
int number = 0;
string value = "5";

number = int.parse(value);
// your code
```

or **2.**

```
int number = 0;
string value = "5";

number = Convert.ToInt32(value);
// your code
```

or **3.**

```
int number = 0;
string value = "5";

bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number); 
if (result == true)
{
    // your code
}
```