# How can I convert the return off my function from (string, string, string) to (int?, int?, string)

Tags: c#

I have a function in my code that returns (string, string, string)

```
return (commonWord.Groups[0].Value, jlpt.Groups[0].Value, wanikaniLevel.Groups[0].Value);
```

What I would like is for it to return (int?, int?, string)

How can I convert a string to an int?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Comment: What is the content of those variables? Do they even represent **numbers**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method which can convert the `string` to `Nullable<int>` if it can convert:

```
public int? ConvertToInt(string value)
{
   return !string.IsNullOfEmpty(value) && int.TryParse(value, out int intValue) ? return (int?)intValue : null;  
}
```

and then can change your return tuple statement as

```
return (ConvertToInt(commonWord.Groups[0].Value), ConvertToInt(jlpt.Groups[0].Value), wanikaniLevel.Groups[0].Value);
```