# Verify if what I receive is an integer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to receive something from WriteLine and associate a variable and after verify is what the user write is a int.

i have this

```
Console.WriteLine("Idade:");
int idade2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (???)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Insira um número não uma string:");
}
else
{
     pessoa.idade = idade2;
}
```

i see some stuff in other post internet etc about int.TryParse ( variavel_string, out variavel_int) but for me dont make sense and i dont think i need it.

in other language is very simple isnumeric(variable) and works in c# i dont know what to do.

What i need put in if condition to work?

Comment: `TryParse` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Well, you indeed need `int.TryParse()`. What's wrong with it ?

Comment: "_i see some stuff in other post internet etc about int.TryParse ( variavel_string, out variavel_int) but for me dont make sense and i dont need it._" `Int.TryParse()` seems like exactly what you need here - why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `TryParse` seems like the most appropriate way to solve your issue.  Consider your code with the change to use it:

```
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int idade2)
{
    pessoa.idade = idade2;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insira um número não uma string:");
}
```

`TryParse` verifies that the entered `string` is an `int` and returns a boolean that indicates this, which you can use to verify it before proceeding.

On the other hand, your use of `Convert`:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Will result in an Exception if the `string` is not a valid `int`.  Not graceful and although it can be handled with a `Try...Catch` block, it's not necessary.