# Get elements from list whose ids are in another

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm new to C# and I ran into a problem.

I have a custom list of lists of my custom type :

```json
items = [
    {
        id = 1,
        ...
    },
    {
        id = 2, 
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

And another list that contains only ids and is a list of strings:

```
myIds = ["1", "2", "3", ...]
```

I need to get those elements from `items` whose ids are in `myIds`.

How to perform that in a good way as I tried:

```
var myNewList = items.Where(p => myIds.Any(p2 => myIds[p2] == p.id));
```

But there is error that string cannont be converted to int?

Comment: did you search for "how to convert a string to an int"? There are dozenzs of similar questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You are trying to compare `int` values with `string` values. Either convert the strings to ints or the ints to strings. I suggest convert the `int` ids to `string` as this always works, where as converting a `string` to an `int` could fail.
2. You are trying to use an id of `myIds` to index `myIds`. This is redundant, since the id `p2` is already an element of `myIds`.

```cs
var myNewList = items
   .Where(p => myIds.Any(p2 => p2 == p.id.ToString()));
                               ^               ^
//    Use p2 instead of myIds[p2]      Convert int to string
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var myNewList = items.Where(p => myIds.Contains( p.id.ToString)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is be because you are comparing int Type with string Type.
Try this:

```
var myNewList = items.Where(p => myIds.Any(p2 => p2 == p.id.ToString());
```