# Convert string to int in foreach loop C# Razor Pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using a `foreach` loop to retrieve data from database and it includes both fields with text and numbers. I need to convert the fields with numbers from string to int to be able to sort the number fields properly.

I tried the following from another thread but it is not working for me:

```
 // Displays the value as string  
Convert.ToInt32(item.property);

// Throws an exception error "The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string out int' has some invalid arguments)"
Int32.TryParse(item.property, out PropertyInt);
```

Followed following:

[How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top)

But this is not working for me in a foreach loop.

Here is my code:

```
@foreach (var item in db.Query(collection))
{
<tr>
<td>item.name</td>
<td>@Convert.ToInt32(item.value);</td>
<td>Int32.TryParse(item.value, out ItemValueInt);</td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: In what way is this "not working"?  Are you getting an error?  An unexpected result?  Something else?  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and clarify the specific problem you are observing.

Comment: Using `int.TryParse` will do the conversion and let you know whether what you are trying to convert is an integer or not (the other two will throw exceptions if the string doesn't represent an integer).  But as @David says, we really can't help you if you don't show us what your code looks like.

Comment: Please also post the context (the foreach loop) for clarity

Comment: @David I added some more information and both examples I am trying in my foreach loop for item.value column.

Comment: @9944990: Can you add information about how this is failing?  What is the specific problem that you are observing?

Comment: Generally speaking this is just bad practice. You shouldn't burden your View/Page with such code. Just retrieve whatever you need on the server side part of this code (probably some GET method) and pass to the View/Page the data in the form and order expected.

Comment: @David I get this error:  "The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string out int' has some invalid arguments)"

Comment: @Steve It is a small project which uses Razor Pages Single Page approach.

Comment: @9944990: And what are the types for `item.value` and for `ItemValueInt`?  Once again, please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Alright then the line is _Int32.TryParse(item.value, out int ItemValueInt)_ but this will just print if the Int32.TryParse is able to convert the value not the value converted

Comment: @9944990: Also, you're showing two different pieces of code, indicating that both of them represent your attempt.  Which one is the actual attempt that is throwing the error?  In the second code sample you also seem to have forgotten to prepend Razor code with `@`, so are those statements even executing?  So far all you're showing us is text that probably kind of looks like the code you're using and a comment with an incomplete error message.  Take some time to update the question with the specific code you're using and the specific error you're seeing.

Comment: The value is in ItemValueInt if conversion succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TryParse to check if the string can be converted to int,and if true, show the `ItemValueInt`,here is a demo:

```
@{ int ItemValueInt;}
@if (Int32.TryParse(item.value, out ItemValueInt))
{
    <td>@ItemValueInt</td>
}
```

Comment: It is throwing exception error: "The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments"