# Compare Selected value between two numbers

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a dropdownlist that is populated by an SQL database.  I am trying to compare the selected values from the SQL dB and it is not working.  Below is what I have so far.

```
if (dropdownlist.SelectedValue >= "5" && dropdownlist.SelectedValue <= "13")
{
  //do something
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What language is this? And when you say "not working", do you get an error message or an incorrect result? My instinct is that `"5"` and `"13"` should be `5` and `13` but without knowing the language it's impossible to say.

Comment: C#, visual Studio throws a red line under the dropdownlist.SelectedValue >= "5" && dropdownlist.SelectedValue <= "13".  I changed the "5" to 5 and same for the 13, and get the same red line.

Comment: Hovering over the Red line in VS it says, "Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'."

Comment: That would be where you're going wrong then. Have a read about [converting a string to an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int).

Comment: Thank you jsheeran.  That did it.  I added int ddl = Int32.Parse(dropdownlist.SelectedValue);   then referrenced the ddl in the if statement.
if (ddl >= 5 && ddl <= 13)
Thank you again!