# How to add two numbers using Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, addition

I want to add two numbers using Console.ReadLine(), but it gives me the error

`Invalid expression term 'int'`

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
      string number1 = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Enter another number:");
      string number2 = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("The sum of those numbers is:");
      Console.WriteLine(int(number1) + int(number2));
    }
  }
}
```

Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Convert.ToInt32()` method to convert from `string` to `int`.

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(number1) + Convert.ToInt32(number2));
```

See [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int) for more examples or alternatives.

---

Note: You write

```
string s = "42";
int i = int(s); // Compiler error Invalid Expression term
```

This syntax is used for type casting in languages like Pascal or Python. But in C based languages like C#, C++ or Java you use a different syntax:

```
string s = "42";
int i = (int)s; // Compiler error invalid cast
```

Round brackets around the type name, not around the value. This will still not work, though, because there is no direct cast from type string to type int in C#. It would work for different types:

```
double d = 42d;
int i = (int)d; // Works
```