# C# Find max int from console imputed string

Tags: c#, string, integer, max

I have this problem to solve in C#: the user enters integers from console (not a fixed number of int, but unlimited numbers of int, as much as he wants) one by one and when the user enters the value 0 (zero) the program should stop and should print the biggest number from the string.

Example: the user enters this integers from console:

```
  4
  -5
  22
  6
  -99
  7
  0
```

and the result should be:

```
22
```

This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class TestNumericDataTypesOperations
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] a = new string[100];
        int max = int.MinValue;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    
            if (a[i] == "0")
            {
                break;
            }

            max = a[i].Max();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }
}
```

If the first thing that I input is zero the it prints "–2147483648".

For 6,4,-9,7,0 in prints "55".

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;

public class TestNumericDataTypesOperations
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int max = int.MinValue; // Initialize max to the smallest possible integer value
        while (true)
        {
            // Read input as a string and convert it to an integer
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int number = int.Parse(input);

            // Break the loop if the input is 0
            if (number == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Update max if the current number is greater than max
            if (number > max)
            {
                max = number;
            }
        }

        // Check if max was updated, implying at least one input was provided before 0
        if (max != int.MinValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(max); // Print the maximum value
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No valid inputs were entered."); // Handle case where 0 is the first input
        }
    }
}
```

You're using the .Max() method on a string, which doesn't behave as you expect. .Max() in this context returns the highest character value in the string based on ASCII
If you would have a List of inteegers you could use .Max()

like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; // Required for using List
using System.Linq; // Required for using .Max()

public class TestNumericDataTypesOperations
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>(); // Create a list to store the input numbers

        while (true)
        {
            // Read input as a string and convert it to an integer
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int number = int.Parse(input); 

            // Break the loop if the input is 0
            if (number == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Add the number to the list
            numbers.Add(number);
        }

        // After the loop, check if any numbers were entered before 0
        if (numbers.Count > 0)
        {
            int max = numbers.Max(); // Use .Max() to find the maximum value in the list
            Console.WriteLine(max); // Print the maximum value
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No valid inputs were entered."); // Handle case where 0 is the first input
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the -2147483648 results from the int.min -> this is the value you assign before.
according to your code you break the loop once you reach 0, before assigning anything to the variable.
then you print the -2147483648

Answer (score 0):

Let's extract a method to enter `int` value (we should work with *integer* values, not *string* ones, note `5 < 40`, but `"5" > "40"`, that's why `string[] a ... max = a.Max()` and alike is a very suspicious approach)

```
private static int ReadInt(string prompt = default) {
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prompt))
      Console.WriteLine(prompt);

  while (true) {
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
      return result;

    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer value. Please, try again.");   
  }
}
```

Then you can implement the loop, note, that you don't want any array:

```
public static void Main() {
  int maxValue = int.MinValue;
  
  while (true) {
    var value = ReadInt();

    if (value == 0)
      break;
    else
      maxValue = Math.Max(value, maxValue);
  }

  Console.WriteLine(maxValue);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2IC9kN)