# Umbraco True/False custom property value parsing issue

Tags: c#, linq, umbraco

dVery confusing on how Umbraco did this, and I'm looking for some sort of explanation if possible. I'm using Umbraco 7. I have a `custom property` on a `doc type` that is a `True/False` (basically a check box).

I'm receiving an error when attempting to parse the `GetPropertyValue`, `object not reference to an object`, which is the `True/False` checkbox.

I do NOT get the error when parsing the `1` INTO an object.

Code:

```
var topics = topicDocType.Select(x => new ForumModel
             {
                   Topic = x.Name,
                   TopicId = x.Id,
/*no error*/       IsClosedForQuestions = x.GetPropertyValue("closedQuestions") == (object)1 ? true : false,
                   Questions = x.Descendants().Where(y => y.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("Question")).Select(y => new Question
                   {
                        QuestionName = y.GetPropertyValue("question").ToString(),
                        QuestionId = y.Id,
                        QuestionDateTime = y.CreateDate,
                        AskedBy = y.GetPropertyValue("askedBy").ToString(),
   /*no error*/         IsClosedForPosts = y.GetPropertyValue("closedPosts") == (object)1 ? true : false,
                        Posts = y.Descendants().Where(z => z.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("Post")).Select(z => new Post
                    .... more code here
```

This doesn't work, and I do not get why:

```
var topics = topicDocType.Select(x => new ForumModel
             {
                   Topic = x.Name,
                   TopicId = x.Id,
/*doesn't work*/   IsClosedForQuestions = int.Parse(x.GetPropertyValue("closedQuestions").ToString()) == 1 ? true : false,
                    .... more code here
```

This doesn't work either:

```
var topics = topicDocType.Select(x => new ForumModel
             {
                   Topic = x.Name,
                   TopicId = x.Id,
/*doesn't work*/   IsClosedForQuestions = x.GetPropertyValue("closedQuestions").ToString() == "1" ? true : false,
                    .... more code here
```

If I create a test variable

```
var test = new ContentService().GetById(2269).GetValue("closedQuestions");
```

The value of `test` is `0`, b/c the check box isn't checked. If I check it, run it again, the value is `1`.

This could just be a C# question that perhaps I knew nothing about, and nothing really to do w/ Umbraco, but I know if I `.ToString()` an object and attempt to check if the value is equal to another string or not, it works.

Appreciate it.

---

**EDIT:**

After reading what Umbraco saves true/false as an int.
[True/False built-in-prop](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/using-umbraco/backoffice-overview/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/True-False)

*True/False is a simple checkbox which saves either 0 or 1, depending on the checkbox being checked or not.*

I also looked up how to parse correctly from an `object(int)`
[Better way to cast object int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745172/better-way-to-cast-object-to-int)

However, this is still not working

```
IsClosedForQuestions = (int)x.GetPropertyValue("closedQuestions") == 1 ? true : false,
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

This DOES work, with retrieving the correct value. Any answers as to why?

```
IsClosedForQuestions = x.GetPropertyValue<int>("closedQuestions") == 1 ? true : false,
```

---

To show you that it's not null:

[image]

After change to `int.Parse(....).ToString()) == 1`

[image]

Comment: What does `x.GetPropertyValue("closedQuestions")` return when you look in the debugger?

Comment: either 1 or 0, depending on if the checkbox is checked. It's an object(int)

Comment: If you're getting a `object not reference to an object` error on that line then it's not 1 or 0 - it's `null`

Comment: What error do you get when trying to cast to `int`?

Comment: Check images above. I can `ToString()` other properties as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `x.GetPropertyValue("closedQuestions")` is returning `null` in some cases (or maybe an `int?` with a null value), which is why you're getting that error when trying to call `ToString()` on it.  If `x.GetPropertyValue<int>("closedQuestions")` works for you then that's great, but I wanted to point out one thing:

You should not compare value-types (like `int`) by casting them to object and using `==`.  Casting to object will box the value type and use referential equality which will fail:

```
object o1 = 1;
object o2 = 1;
Console.WriteLine(o1 == o2);  // will print `false`
```

You could instead use `object.Equals()`:

```
IsClosedForQuestions = object.Equals(x.GetPropertyValue("closedQuestions"),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse it is `x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("propName")`, which might make it a bit easier for comparison and I've never had this method give me an issue.

Also, it's important to note that when you do `getPropertyValue("propName")`, it's an object with no typing, which can cause issues with comparisons. It's just best practice to type the prop out and avoid these issues.