# C# object not parsing to int

Tags: c#, casting

My code looks like this:

```
var score = ((Dictionary<string, object>)entry.Value)["score"];
print("score: " + score + "!");
FBManager.instance.friends[id].score = (int) score;


//OUTPUT: 
//score: 5!
//InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Why can't I cast `score` to int?

I'm pretty sure `entry.Value` is a `Dictionary<string, object>` because I printed `entry.Value.GetType()` and it said exactly this.

Comment: Its unlikely your value is a boxed `int` could it be a decimal or a double, or a string?

Comment: Score wouldn't be an int. Try Convert.ToInt32(score) or parse it

Comment: just do `int.Parse(score);`

Comment: See this question for examples of parsing objects to int: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745172/better-way-to-cast-object-to-int

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(score) did the job! I am retrieving this score as a "number" from firebase, thought it would be fine to just cast to int normally, seems I was wrong. Feel free to write it as an answer.

Comment: there is no such type as `number`

Comment: firebase calls it number, I don't know the exact type but might be a double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what you get when you do: `Console.WriteLine(score.GetType())`

If it is System.String you will need to convert (Convert.ToInt32(score)) or int.Parse(score). If it is System.Int32 you should be fine to cast. If it is anything else (double, decimal, etc.) just do the Convert thing :)

Good Luck!