# Check if variable of any type can be cast into an int in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, integer

`(int)value` is causing exceptions because sometimes value is not an int. I want this code to handle values of multiple types, and cast to an int if possible so I can check what that int's value is (for example, casting an Enum to an int).

checking for `value as int == null` doesn't work because int isn't a nullable type.

checking for `value is int` doesn't appear to do the same thing; an Enum will return false even though it can be converted.

`Int32.TryParse()` doesn't work because the source value must be a string.

I even tried `typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())` but that fails, presumably because it needs an explicit rather than implicit cast.

my best guess is to simply do a try-catch for the cast, but that's also awkward since I want to handle the lack of an exception (if value can be cast into int, do thing), not the exception. since the function just exits after this check I can just put a return in the catch and assume anything after the return can be cast to an int, but yeah that seems pretty hacky and not a great general-purpose solution. Any better ideas?

Edit: this question got closed for being a dupe of [Better way to cast object to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745172/better-way-to-cast-object-to-int)

but 'a better way to cast' to int is not the same as checking if you can pre-cast.

the `as int?` doesn't work because my test Enum still evaluates to null.

`Convert.ToInt32()` doesn't work because it return 0 if the cast failed and the value if it succeeded, making it impossible to tell if it succeeded a cast to 0 or it failed.

OP's solution won't work, it'll evaluate the Enum to its name, not its int index.

Thankfully by thinking about it a tad more myself, I realized there's a pretty obvious solution.

```
bool canCastToInt(object o)
{
    try
    {
        o = (int)o;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Tada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it using a "Try" syntax (like `int.TryParse()`) like so:

```
public static bool TryCastToInt(object obj, out int result)
{
    try
    {
        result = (int) obj;
        return true;
    }

    catch
    {
        result = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, note that this cast will fail unless the object is an enum with underlying type `int` or an actual `int`. For example, it will fail for `short` and `double`.

If you want it to work for any type that can be explicitly cast to `int` you can implement it using `Convert.ChangeType()` like so:

```
public static bool TryCastToInt(object obj, out int result)
{
    try
    {
        result = (int) Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(int));
        return true;
    }

    catch
    {
        result = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

To see the difference, try the following console app:

```
namespace Console1;

public static class Program
{
    enum ShortEnum: short { Item }
    enum IntEnum { Item }

    public static void Main()
    {
        test(1.234, "double");
        test("x", "string");
        test((short)1, "short");
        test(ShortEnum.Item, "short enum");
        test(IntEnum.Item, "int enum");
        test(1, "int");
    }

    static void test(object obj, string name)
    {
        if (TryCastToInt(obj, out int value))
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} = {value}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Could not cast {name} to int.");
    }

    public static bool TryCastToInt(object obj, out int result)
    {
        try
        {
            // result = (int)obj;
            result = (int) Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(int));
            return true;
        }

        catch
        {
            result = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Run this to see the results, and then comment out the `ChangeType()` line and uncomment the `(int)` line and run it again.